# Left Outer Join with Complex conditions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, t-sql, left-join

How can I do an SQL Query like this with Linq?

```sql
select DISTINC
....
   from Table1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
     ON Table2.Field1 = Table1.Field1 AND
        Table2.Field2 = Table1.Field2 AND
        Table2.Field3 = Table1.Field3 AND
        (
        ( Table1.Field4 = 'Something' AND ( Table2.Field5 = 'Something'
                                 OR Table2.Field5 = 'Something' ) )
        OR
        ( Table1.Field4 = 'Something' AND ( Table2.Field5 = 'Something'
                                 OR Table2.Field5 = 'Something' ) )
        OR
        ( Table1.Field4 = 'Something' AND ( Table2.Field5 = 'Something'
                                 OR Table2.Field5 = 'Something'
                                 OR Table2.Field5 = 'Something' ) )
        )

   where 
   ....
   order by ...
```

I have been doing LEFT OUTER JOINS in LinQ but only with equals like this

```C#
from Table1 in ....
  join Table2 in ....
    on new { Table1.Field1, Table1.Field2 }
    equals new { Table2.UNField1V, Table2.Field2 }
    into Join1
  from Name in Join1.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where
  ....
  select new { ... }
```

But I have no idea to do something like that with complex conditions like the SQL Query that I have written.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JuanDYB where is the `Dtos_Gra` table in the from clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from t1 in Table1
from t2 in Table2.Where(t2 => t2.Field1 == t1.Field1 && /* ... complex join condition */)
                 .DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    t1.AnyReferenceField,
    (int?)t2.AnotherInt32Field // !
    /* ... */
}
```

Just do not forget to convert t2's value fields to be nullable. Otherwise you will get exception similar to `The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.`.

If you want query syntax:

```
from t1 in Table1
from t2 in (from t2 in Table2
            where t2.Field1 == t1.Field1 && /* ... complex join condition */
            select t2).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Hello: Thanks for your reply. Your example helps me and it's working well. Also thanks for your advertisement about nullable objects.